# calculating values through loop

Tags: loops

I have a variable length list of values (one set in made up from three consecutive values, i.e., `r g b`). I'm calculating the average from the set and then comparing them in order to sort from lowest to highest number. My code is very long and repetitive so I try to cut it down by using loop:

```
//seps is an array containing numeric values
for 
(k=1;k<seps.length;)
{
this ['r'+k] = seps[l]; 
this ['g'+k] = seps[l+1]; 
this ['b'+k] = seps[l+2]; 
var R = this.r0; 
var G = this.g0;
var B = this.b0;
}
```

It is creating the variables correctly as I can check their values (r1, g1, b1, etc) but when trying to use the R or G or B it comes up with NaN. Is there any other way of specifying the value of R, G and B?

Comment: Hello, Can you please specify the language? Also, where you measure the balues of `R`, `G` and `B`?

Comment: it is javascript, the values come from xml file, I think they may be set as text - should that be changed into numbers?

Comment: Improve grammar to make question understandable.